# Why a inverted range in Swift crashes at runtime instead of at compilation time

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, crash, runtime-error

Looking at this simple piece of Swift code:

```
for index in 10...6 {
    print(index)
}
```

I wonder why it crashes at runtime, instead of being detected at compilation time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think it *should* be detected at compile time?

The underlying function `...` is defined as

```
public func ...<Pos : ForwardIndexType where Pos : Comparable>(start: Pos, end: Pos) -> Range<Pos>
```

It is a normal function like any other. It simply contains a check that ensures that `end` is not smaller than `start` at runtime. There is nothing the compiler can do here.

It is like asking why the compiler does not detect a crash in the following code a t compile time but crashes at run time:

```
func bla(input:Int) {
    let k = input / input
}
bla(0)
```

The compiler does not check that a call to a method succeeds, it verifies that the arguments match, optimizes the code, etc. It does simply not check every execution path. You could of course *build* a compiler that does that, but that is going to be difficult. Consider introducing a static variable that changes the behavior of `bla` every time you call it, same goes for the `...` - of course the compiler *could* check that the statement `10...6` is valid, but it simply does not do that because that is not the job of the compiler.